# python iterate over and select values from list of zipped arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have several multidimensional arrays that have been zipped into a single list and am trying to remove values from the list according to a selection criteria applied to a single array. Specifically I have the 4 arrays, all of which have the same shape, that have all been zipped into one list of arrays:

```
    in: array1.shape
    out: (5,3)
    ...
    in: array4.shape
    out: (5,3)

    in: array1
    out: ([[0, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [0, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 0]])

    in: array4
    out: ([[20, 16, 20],
          [15, 19, 17],
          [21, 24, 23],
          [22, 22, 26],
          [27, 24, 23]])
    in: fullarray = zip(array1,...,array4)

    in: fullarray[0]
    out: (array([0, 1, 1]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([33, 34, 35]), array([20, 16, 20]))
```

I am trying to iterate over the values from a single target array within each set of arrays and select the values from each array with the same index as the target array when the value equals 20. I doubt I explained that clearly so I'll give an example.

```
     in: fullarray[0]
     out: (array([0, 1, 1]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([33, 34, 35]), array([20, 16, 20]))

     what I want is to iterate over the values of the fourth array in the list for 
     fullarray[x] and where the value = 20 to take the value of each array with 
     the same index and append them into a new list as an array.

      so the output for fullarray[0] would be ([[0, 3, 33, 20]), [1, 5, 35, 20]])
```

My previous attempts have all generated a variety of error messages (example below). Any help would be appreciated.

```
    in: for i in g:
          for n in i:
              if n == 3:
                 for k in n:
                     if k == 0:
                        newlist.append(i[k])

    out: for i in fullarray:
      2     for n in i:
----> 3         if n == 3:
      4             for k in n:
      5                 if k == 0:

     ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
     Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: The title is misleading, your arrays are not nested, when you zip them you still have a flat array, containing tuples. Run the code in my answer you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit for modified question:**

Here's a piece of code that's doing what you what. The time complexity could probably be improved though.

```
from numpy import array

fullarray = [(array([0, 1, 1]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([33, 34, 35]), array([20, 16, 20]))]

newlist = []
for arrays in fullarray:
    for idx, value in enumerate(arrays[3]):
        if value == 20:
            newlist.append([array[idx] for array in arrays])

print newlist
```

**Old answer:** Assuming all your arrays are the same size you could do the following:
`full[idx]` contains a tuple with the values of all your arrays at the index `idx` in the order you zipped them.

```
import numpy as np

ar1 = np.array([1] * 8)
ar2 = np.array([2] * 8)

full = zip(ar1, ar2)
print full

newlist = []
for idx, v in enumerate(ar1):
    if v != 0:
        newlist.append(full[idx]) # Here you get a tuple such as (ar1[idx], ar2[idx])
```

But `if len(ar1) > len(ar2)` it is going to throw and exception so keep that in mind and adjust your code accordingly.